# Convolution for two random variables

Tags: statistics, convolution

In the textbook i'm currently reading it is said that for two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ density function of variable $Z=X+Y$ can be found from the equation:
$$
g(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_1(x)f_2(z-x) \, dx
$$
And if possible values of arguments are positive, then
$$
g(z) = \int_0^z f_1(x)f_2(z-x) \, dx
$$
Why the upper bound $\infty$ has been replaced with argument $z$ at the second ingeral?

Comment: This is known as *convolution* (not composition), and gives the density of $X+Y$. So if $X$ and $Y$ are positive with probability $1$, then $X+Y$ is positive with probability $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the possible values (range of the two r.v.'s) are non-negative, then both $x$ and $z-x$ should be non-negative in the integrand (as $f_1(x) = 0$ and $f_2(z-x)=0$ otherwise, respectively).  This implies $x\geq 0$ *and* $x\leq z$.

Hence the bounds $\int_0^z$ on the integral.

Comment: I got the idea, but what means "as $f1(x)=0$ and$ f2(z−x)=0f2(z−x)=0$ otherwise, respectively"?

Comment: It means that if $x < 0$, $f_1(x)=0$; while if $x > z$, $f_2(z-x) = 0$. In both cases the product inside the integral is $0$.

Comment: I see, but why is that so?

Comment: Because if the only values the r.v's can take are non-negative, then their pdfs are zero on the negative numbers (there is no probability mass there).